# Where is the repository information(like url , working branch) stored in .git folder?

Tags: python, git, github, automation

I am trying to write a github automation script but there is an issue that i am facing i.e. i don't know where the repository information i being stored in .git folder. By searching the files manually i found that .git\config file has some information but it is really inconsistent as sometimes the information is not there. Can someone tell me which file should i look into for repository information(i.e. URL , working branch).

This is my code to get the URL and branch from the .git\config file:-

```py
import os
mypath = os.getcwd()
infofile = mypath + '/.git/config'

def takeInfo():
    print('No Existing repo info found\n')
    url = str(input('Enter the Github Repo URL: '))
    branch = str(input('Enter the branch: '))
    info = ['n' , url , branch]
    return info

def checkinfoInDir():
    if (os.path.exists(infofile)):
        print('Repo Info Found:-')
        with open(infofile, "r") as f:
            info = f.readlines()
            # print(info)
            for ele in info:
                if('url' in ele):
                    url = info[info.index(ele)].split()[2]

                if('branch' in ele):
                    branch = info[info.index(ele)].split()[1].split('"')[1]
            info = [url , branch]
    else:
        info = takeInfo()
    return info
```

Comment: `GitPython` is recommended.

Comment: @ElpieKay I want to minimize the use of external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the current branch, use `git symbolic-ref` or `git rev-parse`:

- `git symbolic-ref` works in all cases where `HEAD` is a symbolic ref, including the case where it is a symbolic name for a branch that does not yet exist.<sup>1</sup>  It fails when `HEAD` is detached, i.e., points directly to a commit.
- `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` works in all cases where `HEAD` identifies some commit.  It fails when `HEAD` is a symbolic name for a branch that does not yet exist, and when `HEAD` is detached, it comes up with the name `HEAD`.

To find a URL for some remote, use `git config --get remote.remote.url`.  Note that if Git is configured for a triangular workflow, this is the *fetch* URL, not the *push* URL, so check for the result of `git config --get remote.remote.pushurl` to see if there is a separate push URL.

Note that there can be any number of remotes, including none.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls this an *orphan branch* or an *unborn branch*, depending on which part of Git is doing the calling.  To get into this state, create a new empty repository—you'll be on whatever branch name you choose as your initial name, but it won't exist as there are no commits and no branch names can exist until there are commits—or use `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`.

To get into *detached HEAD* state, use `git checkout` with any valid commit identifier that is not a branch name, or use `git checkout --detach` or `git switch --detach` with or without any valid commit identifier.

To get *out* of detached HEAD state, use `git checkout` or `git switch` with a valid branch name (including the various cases where these commands create a *new* branch name, then attach `HEAD` to it).

Comment: I just have one more question , are these commands consistent over all operating systems?

Comment: @AntrikshMisri: yes. Invoking them isn't (spawn vs fork+exec, for instance), but fortunately Python has already papered over this part.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example config file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[submodule]
    active = .
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/sample/sample.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

it has *ini* file format, so you use a simple *ini* python library to parse this file.

Comment: It's a *modified* INI file format (or, more or less equivalent in terms of effect, there's no single INI format, but rather a loosely related set of formats, all slightly incompatible, and all called "INI files"). So not all libraries will read all config files. When interacting with Git programmatically, it is probably best to use `git config` to do that. (This doesn't mean you *can't* invoke a python INI file library directly, just ... be careful.)